# Maven disable workspace resolution in POM

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

Is there some way to stop Maven from resolving artefacts in the Eclipse workbench?

I know I can set it manually, but I would be nice if it can be set through the POM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I don't think so. In my opinion Maven even should not bother about IDE settings. This would only mess up the POM (like already done with the eclipse `lifecycle-mapping` configuration for plugins in eclipse).

I would support if this would be a global setting of the m2e plugin of eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There's a plugin that will do it: see http://code.google.com/p/mad-mvntools-m2eclipsegen/

Tested and this works fine (it's available in mvn central so no additional repos).

Comment: Caution! The [maven-eclipse-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) you mention is NOT the [Maven integration(M2E)](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) Franz Kafka is talking about.

Comment: @K.Claszen - you're quite right, I was talking rubbish before.  Corrected answer. +1 thanks!

Comment: Strange as the op's question is your answer is not exactly what the op was looking for, but +1 for the idea because separation of concerns seems to indicate putting this in a pom would be a bad idea.

Comment: @earcam This seems to be the project preference which can easily be changed manually via the project context menu (Maven -> Disable Workspace Resolution) as mentioned in the question. Why should someone edit the preference file?

Comment: @K.Claszen - I seem to have been blinded by beer on Friday and talking nonsense.  Updated answer again...